# 400 Bad Request with Guzzle from the Microsoft Oauth endpoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, guzzle

We're trying to get the access_token from the Microsoft OAUTH endpoint with Guzzle, but always getting 400 - Bad request response. Any idea on that?
Here's the Guzzle request:

```
$r = $this->client->createRequest('POST', 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token', [
        'body' => [
          'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
          'client_id'     => 'foo',
          'client_secret' => 'bar',
          'code'          => 'baz',
          'redirect_uri'  => 'http://my.app/oauth/r_url'
        ]
      ]);

$res = $this->client->send($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'resource' parameter to your body.

Answer (score 0):

Your token request looks good. Resource param isn't required because it is encoded in the code (was supplied as part of the authorization request).

Make sure the redirect_uri value exactly matches the uri on which the authorization code was sent.

Comment: Dushyant, It comes from the same ENV variable.

Comment: I changed the Guzzle package for CURL implementation, and the response was "Authentication failed. Authorization Code is not valid." So I regenerated the authorization code, changed it in the POST token request but getting the same Authentication failed message.

Comment: Can you grab an http trace (of the entire flow) and send it over? Contact me on http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/contact - I'll give you my email.